# How should I write my code to soupFindall('tr') and not something that equal my column list

Tags: python, findall

I want to pull data from a website. I got everything but I need to clean the data.

I have tried this script but added "!=column_List" in my for loop, but I don't know how its done.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def make_soup(url):
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
return soupdata

column_List = ['Name','Symbol','Currency','ISIN','Sector','ICB Code','Fact Sheet']
soup = make_soup("https://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/aktier/listed-companies/nordic-large-cap")
for record in soup.findAll('tr')!=column_List:  ##(comment I added !=)
print(record.text)
```

I'm going to pull the ticker data, format it and use the currency information to add the correct yah*o tag. .st for Swedish stocks .co for Copenhagen Denmark etc

Comment: `soup.findAll('tr')` will find all `<tr>` elements as a list, you are comparing this to a list of strings. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `for record in soup.findAll('tr'): if record.text not in collumn_List: print(record.text)`?

Comment: Thanks, I'm a beginner.  I want to clean the data up and use the tickers.
Maybee I'm doing it totaly wrong :) but I did get it to work pretty good.
let me show u an example of the data i got without my collumn_List and != statement.

Name
Symbol
Currency
ISIN
Sector
ICB Code
Fact Sheet


TRATON
8TRA
SEK
DE000TRAT0N7
Industrials
2700

Comment: Feels like I need to find a way to remove the columns and some blank space from the data and I'm done

Comment: You want to find all `tr`s that have the columns you've defined in `collumn_list`?

Comment: Its hard for me to tell about programming I'm reading and checking youtube tutorials for trying keep up. I know what the final produkt should look like.
My data now is, name,ticker,currency,a number, sector,some number
I would like to grab the ticker, if there is a "space replace with -" and if currency was sek add .st currency was dkk add .co 
So for volvo stock ticker is volv b that i need to replace to volv-b and add .st
final volvo ticker is then volv-b.st

Comment: I think I found a the solution, i will uppdate this when i got it to work if anyone else wants to se